# Springboot : parsing json input without converting to java objects

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am currently involve in a spring-boot project, which act as a decision making server, It calls several rest endpoints, then convert those input into java objects using jackson,run some rules, aggregate those results and send back to the client. My question is can we use the Jackson, (Streaming API or Tree Model) to partially parse the input json from the endpoints and create the aggregated responses, without using the Jackson Data Binding model. The requirement is to remove the input contract from the decision making server (Rather remove the dependency from the whole payload and expecting some mandatory fields). If this is possible how the swagger contract would work? I am not sure this is a dumb question though.

Sample Input Data

```
 {
    "field1" : "value1",
    "mandatoryField1" : "value2",
    "mandatoryField2" : "value2",
    "field2" : "value3",
    {
      some array
    }
}
```

Lets assume that I am getting above payload, and I'm only considering about the mandarotyFiled values, so no point of parsing the whole input payload.

And if I don't convert, or have the whole response for the client in a Java bean, how would I create the swagger for the decision making server. Is this doable?

Comment: I don't think this is a dumb question, but it sure isn't a really clear question :p Joke aside, can you provide some data example of what you want to get in parameters and in output?

Comment: You can parse the input as a `JSONObject` instead and manually get or set the fields. This way you have no real input contract.

Comment: I have added some sample data.  @NicoVanBelle Then what happen to the swagger contract of the server, since we don't have/mapped the response in a java bean.

Comment: Instead of auto generate swagger, define it yourself